# How do I get an image to line up with the text in Bootstrap nav list?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, erb

I'm trying to align an image with some text within a list item. I can't seem to get them to align though (see image).

How can I get the text and image to align? I am using the default CSS files from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and have no customized CSS for any of the classes or elements shown in my markup.

Markup:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><%= link_to "Connect", "#", class: "footer-heading" %></li>
        <li><%= image_tag "facebook.png", size: "32"%><%= link_to "Facebook", "url" %></li>
        <li><%= image_tag "facebook.png", size: "32"%><%= link_to "Facebook", "url" %></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: you've tagged this as css, but shown us none of your css.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS put either:

```
ul img{ display: inline-block; }
```

or

```
ul img{ float: left; }
```

Which should cause the image to be displayed inline with the text.

Alternatively add the image as a background image to the ul and position the text using padding. You can use different images by applying a class (of, for example 'facebook_icon') to the ul.

Comment: Tried this but the images/list items ended up going diagonal (moving) across the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap `list-inline`..

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li>-</li>
        <li>-</li>
        <li>-</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### [Bootply](http://bootply.com/99609)