# How do I prevent this list from moving across the page?

Tags: css

I'm trying to align an image with some text within a list item. I had previously asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493884/how-do-i-get-an-image-to-line-up-with-the-text-in-bootstrap-nav-list) but the solution(s) appeared to present a new challenge and I wanted to include an image to show what was going wrong.

How can I get the text and image to align in my list and prevent this (see image) diagonal behaviour from occurring?

Markup:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><%= link_to "Connect", "#", class: "footer-heading" %></li>
        <li><%= image_tag "facebook.png", size: "32"%><%= link_to "Facebook", "url" %></li>
        <li><%= image_tag "facebook.png", size: "32"%><%= link_to "Facebook", "url" %></li>
        <li><%= image_tag "facebook.png", size: "32"%><%= link_to "Facebook", "url" %></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
li img{ 
   float: left;
 }
```

With the current CSS I am getting this effect:

[image]

Comment: use float for `li` element like this: `li{ float:left }`

Comment: set a height on your li that is greater than the height of the image and possibly add a top margin to the li

Comment: please show your resulting markup, not the asp code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`li{ overflow:hidden; }` or `li{ float:left; clear:both; }`

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap `list-inline`..

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li>-</li>
        <li>-</li>
        <li>-</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Bootply](http://bootply.com/99609)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are looking for a vertical list but which is neatly aligned left. Isn't it?

You can do away with `img` tags and use backgrounds on `li`.

Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/V2Zxb/**

Give a class to your anchors, and use left padding to offset the logos:

```
a.fb {
    background-image: url(facebook.png);
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 36px;
}
```